# Sphinx search very slow in Yii framework

Tags: php, search, yii, sphinx

My website is used yii framework and sphinx search engineer. But recently the search function seems very slow in webpage. When I use command in server

```
  search -c etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf xxx
```

It can return results very fast. But search the same word in website interface it return result very slow.
Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) DONT use `search` tool. Its not realistic.

2) Stackoverflow is a site for programming questions. There are other forums for sysadmin style questions.

3) If you want a helpful answer, you need to write a good question. There is pretty much NO details in your above question, nobody could even begin to guess what your issue could be...